# Laravel Socialite Stateless Authentication API (Social Providers - Facebook/Google) + Mobile Application

Tags: html, angular, laravel, typescript, ionic-framework

Please guys help me how to integrate my laravel socialite authentication (login with fb or google) with my ionic/angular application.
I have it working 100% on my website (Laravel) but now I want to use it as a backend (API) to my frontend (ionic).
& in ionic I imported the facebook plugin and it's returning the accessToken, I just want to connect them together. Please Help

The code in ionic is correct, am just stuck on Laravel function, I don't know what to write in it:

The original login with fb/google function in Laravel, not the API:

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
    {
        try{
            $userinfo = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
        }catch (\Exception $e){
            return redirect()->intended('/');
        }

        Log::debug($userinfo->getId());
        $socialProvider = SocialProvider::where('provider_id',$userinfo->getId())->first();
        if(!$socialProvider){

           
                Log::debug('CONTINUE 1.1');
                $user = User::firstOrCreate(
                    ['name'=>$userinfo->getName(), 'display_name' => $userinfo->getName()] //Create With including email
                );
                
                Log::debug('CONTINUE 1.2');
                $user->socialProvider()->create([
                    'provider_id' =>$userinfo->getId(),
                    'provider' => $provider
                ]);
           
        }
        else
        {
            Log::debug('CONTINUE 2.1');
            $user=$socialProvider->user;
            Log::debug('CONTINUE 2.2');
        }
        
        if ($user != null)
        {
            Log::debug('CONTINUE 3.1');
            auth()->login($user);
        }
        Log::debug('hi');
        Log::debug($provider);

        return redirect()->intended('/')->with('success', '');
           }
```

now the question is how I can convert this function to API? I know I should put "stateless" but where exactly? and what it should return?

my ionic function:

```
 fbLogin()
{

  this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'email'])
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status === 'connected') {
        this.isLoggedIn = true;

        this.getUserDetail(res.authResponse.userID);
        this.authService.mobileProviderLogin(res.authResponse.accessToken).subscribe(
          res => { 
            console.log("accesstooooken2")
            console.log(res);
            }, err => {
                 console.log(err);
            });
        console.log("res");
        console.log(res);
        this.route.navigate(['/home']);
      } else {
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
      }
    }),  (error: any) => {
      console.log(error);
}}
```

My ionic service function:

```
  mobileProviderLogin(postData: any) {

    return this.https.post(this.env.API_URL + 'auth/mobileProviderLogin',  postData 
    )
  }
```

is the service correct? it should be post or get?

and in laravel route, the url should be post or get?